# Calculate data day by day and create monthly data in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, merge, nosql, aggregate, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection in mongo, and its data is;

```
[
    {
        "_id": "AAAAA",
        "date": "17-01-2020",
        "query": {
            "user_overview":{ "total": 5, "view": 15},
            "device":[
                { "name": "Samsung", "value": 3 },
                { "name": "Huawei", "value": 2 },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "BBBBB",
        "date": "18-01-2020",
        "query": {
            "user_overview":{ "total": 2, "view": 8 },
            "device":[
                { "name": "IPhone", "value": 4 },
                { "name": "Samsung", "value": 1},
            ]
        }
    },

    ... # goes like this 

]
```

What i want to do is sum and merge day by day on same month and create monthly data like below

```
[
    {
        "_id": "------",
        "date": "31-01-2020",
        "query": {
            "user_overview":{ "total": 133, "view": 399 },
            "device":[
                { "name": "Samsung", "value": 32 },
                { "name": "Huawei", "value": 49 },
                { "name": "IPhone", "value": 24 },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "------",
        "date": "29-02-2020",
        "query": {
            "user_overview":{ "total": 534, "view": 348 },
            "device":[
                { "name": "Samsung", "value": 78 },
                { "name": "Huawei", "value": 44 },
                { "name": "IPhone", "value": 19 },
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I made some research on it, but couldn't find any useful information. 
Any comment will be helpful for me.